# How to change the header text color of my settings?

Tags: android

[wallpicker app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImHmI.jpg)

I was actually trying to make an overlay theme that override my settings and other apps, I've somehow successfully make it transparent and change the font color but one thing i couldn't change is the header of it, in the image you'll see a "**Settings**" which isn't white color, that's my current problem, it also happened on other header apps just like "**wallpaper picker app**" and more apps

Already tried:

```
<item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/primary_dark_device_default_settings</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">#40000000</item>
<item name="android:windowShowWallpaper">true</item>
<item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
```

adding a `textColor` but it didn't change the header text color or was it called an action bar?

also textColorPrimary doesn't do anything at all? and im on api 33

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jsNN.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jsly.png

Comment: This is custom drawer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. In your original theme

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponent.DayNight.NoActionBar">

    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/CustomToolbar</item>

</style>
```

your theme settings as follow:

```
<style name="CustomToolbar" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: it did not work, btw can you look on my compiled overlay? to see which one is the needed for me to put?